# testing - accessing Seed data in Cypress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cypress, e2e-testing, seeding

I would like to access the seeded database during the test

### my setup:

my seeds for the test contain:

```rb
FactoryBot.create_list(:user, 10)
```

my User factory looks like:

```rb
  factory :user { email { Faker::Internet.unique.email } }
```

(so there is no way for me to know their email addresses beforehands)

### my goal

at one point in my tests I would love to do something like:

```js
    cy.get('body')
      .should('contain', `${user.last.email}`)
```

is there a way to achieve that result inside a Cypress test?

Answer (score 2):

The [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/), [a payment application to demonstrate real-world usage of Cypress testing methods, patterns, and workflows](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app), demonstrates how to access seeded data via a remote command implemented in a way that is language and framework agnostic.

It is done using a Cypress Command, [`cy.database`](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/support/commands.ts#L277-L299), which calls a [Cypress Task depending upon the operation (filter or find)](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/plugins/index.ts#L33-L39).

The tasks issue an API request to a [test API endpoint](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/plugins/index.ts#L14) which is [only exposed for the test environment](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/backend/app.ts#L65-L67).

This technique can be used to access seed data from a remote or local instance, and can be used to drive tests, as demonstrated in [the notifications spec](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app/blob/develop/cypress/tests/ui/notifications.spec.ts#L22-L26).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the https://github.com/shakacode/cypress-on-rails gem to get this working.

After setting up the gem your code could look like this:

```js
 cy.appFactories([
   ['create_list', 'user', 9],
   ['create', 'user', email: 'myuser@email.com'],
 ])
 cy.visit('/users')
 cy.get('body').should('contain', 'myuser@email.com')
```